# How to put a UIScrollView on UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I'm using the `UIPageViewController` in my storyboard, and I add some other `viewControllers` with a `UITextField` on the `UIPageViewController`.

However when you click on the `UITextField`, the keyboard pops over the `UITextField`, so you basically **can't see** the `UITextField`.

I already got a class for this which uses the `UIScrollView` but I cannot drag and drop the `ScrollView` onto the `PageViewController` in my storyboard.

Is there any other option how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't how a UIPageViewController works. You cannot do any designing of a UIPageViewController in a storyboard! Its view is purely for displaying the view of its child. You have to have a UIViewController which you supply to the UIPageViewController in `setViewControllers:...` and in the data source calls (`pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:`). That UIViewController's view is what you want to design.

Here's some code:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_page_view_controller

Also make a new project from the Page-Based Application template. It shows you what to do.

As for the part about scrolling the UITextField out of the way of the keyboard, this is a standard problem and there are many answers on Stack Overflow already. See, for example, my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15802546/341994

Comment: I'm searching for another way, maybe just in my other UIViewController how I can do this

Comment: @matt - can't he define vcs in storyboard, give them storyboard ids, then build a bunch of them using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier?

Comment: @danh Yes; that's what I mean when I said "That UIViewController's view is what you want to design." But he cannot connect the UIPageViewController to those UIViewControllers in the storyboard; all that work is done in in code, as I also said.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I've done in code... I just want to know how I can avoid that the keyboard pops up before the UITextField

Comment: Well then, you asked your question very unclearly. This has nothing to do with UIPageViewController at all! See my edit.